# Issue with a global variable setting

Tags: python, global-variables, pong

The program is supposed to update the value of the global variable `int_choice` every time a player scores (it's a pong game)

`int_choice` can only have a value of 1 or 0. If it's 1, the function `left_or_right` "tells" the ball to go right, if it's 0, the ball goes left.

`int_choice` is updated in few places: at the beginning it's initialized, then in the `left_or_right()` function, then in the `draw()` function.

Every time the user scores, the ball should be respawned from the centre of the table towards that user, but the ball always respawns twice in the same direction and then twice in the opposite direction and so on, regardless of who was the last one to score.

Here's the code:

```
import random

int_choice = random.randint(0,1)
direc = None

def left_or_right():
    global direc, int_choice
    if int_choice == 0:
        direc = "LEFT"
    elif int_choice == 1:
        direc = "RIGHT"
    return direc

def spawn_ball(direction):
    left_or_right()
    global ball_pos, ball_vel # these are vectors stored as lists
    ball_pos = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2]
    if direction == "LEFT":
        ball_vel[0] = (random.randrange(12, 25)*(-0.1))
        print "Velocity[0]: ", ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] =  (random.randrange(6, 19)*(-0.1))
    elif direction == "RIGHT":
        ball_vel[0] = (random.randrange(12, 25)*(0.1))
        print "Velocity[0]: ", ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] =  (random.randrange(6, 19)*(-0.1))
        print "Velocity[1]: ", ball_vel[1]

def new_game():
    global paddle1_pos, paddle2_pos, paddle1_vel, paddle2_vel, direc
    global score1, score2, 
    spawn_ball(direc)
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0

def draw(canvas):
    global remaining_names, score1, score2, paddle1_pos, paddle2_pos,          ball_pos, ball_vel, BALL_RADIUS, direc
    global int_choice


    # update ball
    ball_pos[0] += ball_vel[0]
    ball_pos[1] += ball_vel[1]
    if ball_pos[1] - BALL_RADIUS <= 0:
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1] + (ball_vel[1] * (-2))     
    elif ball_pos[1] + BALL_RADIUS >= HEIGHT:
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1] + (ball_vel[1] * (-2))
    elif ball_pos[0] - BALL_RADIUS <= (0 + PAD_WIDTH):
        if (ball_pos[1] > paddle1_pos) and (ball_pos[1] < (paddle1_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)):
            ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0] + (ball_vel[0] * (-2.1))
        else:
            int_choice = 1
            spawn_ball(direc)
            score2 = score2 + 1

    elif (ball_pos[0] + BALL_RADIUS) >= (WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH):
        if (ball_pos[1] > paddle2_pos) and (ball_pos[1] < (paddle2_pos + PAD_HEIGHT)):
            ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0] + (ball_vel[0] * (-2.1))
        else:
            int_choice = 0
            spawn_ball(direc)
            score1 = score1 + 1
```

Comment: `random.randint(0,1)` is an alias for `random.randrange(2)`. Consider using the later.

Comment: Why are you even using *two* globals that mean the same thing? And your `left_or_right()` function could just be replaced by a list: `directions = ['LEFT', 'RIGHT']`, and `directions[int_choice]` would translate the integer to text each time you need the text.

Comment: You also pass in the direction into `spawn_ball()`, which then *calls `left_or_right()` as well*. Why pass in the direction, then call a function to set it again? The function returns the direction too, but you ignore the return value everywhere.

Comment: More to the point, the call to `left_or_right()` in `spawn_ball()` flips the sense of `int_choice` from what you want. You should probably remove that call.

Comment: However, I don't see anywhere in this code that `int_choice` is otherwise set  in a weirdly alternating manner in this code.

Comment: It looks like you're using "global" as a kind of variable declaration. For example, you declare the globals "score1" and "score2" twice. Same with direc. You don't have to declare variables in Python, the assignment *is* the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass in the **old** value of `direc`, before `left_or_right` is called.

Say, you set `int_cohice` to 1:

```
int_choice = 1
spawn_ball(direc)  # old value of `direc`, nothing changed this yet
```

then in `spawn_ball()`:

```
def spawn_ball(direction):
    left_or_right()
```

so `direction` is set the *old* value, but `left_or_right()` sets it to a *new* value, which is then *entirely ignored* in `spawn_ball()`. You use `direction` throughout the function.

The quick fix is to use the return value of `left_or_right()`; or use the `direc` global. Since either operates on globals, there is no point in passing in `direc` here:

```
int_choice = 1
spawn_ball()  # don't pass anything in
```

and

```
def spawn_ball():
    direction = left_or_right()
```

However, the better way is to *always* pass in a direction, and completely remove the (double) globals.

Just pass in a number, you can give that number symbolic names:

```
LEFT, RIGHT = 0, 1  # symbolic names for direction

def spawn_ball(direction):
    ball_pos = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2]
    if direction == LEFT:  # using the global symbolic name
        return ball_pos, [
            random.randrange(12, 25)*(-0.1),
            random.randrange(6, 19)*(-0.1)]
    else:   # naturally the other option is going to be RIGHT
        return ball_pos, [
            random.randrange(12, 25)*(0.1)
            random.randrange(6, 19)*(-0.1)]
```

Note that the function **returns** new ball positions and velocity; store the result when you call the function:

```
ball_pos, ball_vel = spawn_ball(direction)
```

Perhaps the `draw` function still treats these as globals, but that's no longer a concern for the `spawn_ball()` function at the very least.

Now all you need to do is set one *local* variable to either `LEFT` or `RIGHT` to spawn a ball and pass that variable into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem exists because you update the variable at the wrong time in your code. Let's look at an example of what happens after a game ends.

```
int_choice = 0
spawn_ball(direc)
```

You set int_choice to 0, then you call spawn_ball(direc), but direc is the **old** direction - it hasn't changed yet, only int_choice has. So now direc has been bound to the "direction" variable in your spawn_ball function. Even though spawn_ball immediately calls left_or_right(), that will **only update direc, not direction**, meaning that spawn_ball will continue with the same direction it was originally passed in, no matter what the call to left_or_right did.

The quick solution would be to say

```
def spawn_ball(direction):
    direction = left_or_right()
```

Which will likely fix that problem. However, I would suggest you refactor your code quite a bit - it is very bad style. Passing around global variables as you are is so prone to errors like this one - using locals passed around through function calls is a much better option.